# On ring isomorphisms

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings, galois-rings

Is it possible to have ring isomorphisms between some subsets of size $s^k$ of Galois ring $\Bbb Z_2^{s^k}$ and the full Galois ring $\Bbb Z_s^k$?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least for $s\ne 2$, since this subset must be a subring of order/size s^k. In particular, it is an additive subgroup in the group $\Bbb Z_2^{s^k}(+)$. Hence $s^k$ must divide $2^{s^k}$.

Comment: Do you want to define other operations on $\Bbb Z_2^{s^k}$? Anyway my resoning is true, since you will have other ring of the same order.

Comment: I cannot take this as an answer. It is not rigorous enough. " since this subset must be a subring of order/size .." may be there is a clever way to force this for just the chosen subset leaving this subset closed under special algebraic operations.

However, I understand what you are saying about divisibility of order.

Comment: Yes may be there is a non-natural operation in the subset that is just compatible with $\Bbb Z_s^k$ while the operation while extendible to the whole ring produces disjoint closed sets under the algebraic operation. May be the $0$ in $\Bbb Z_s^k$ need not be mapped to traditional $0$ in the other ring? That is, the new $0$ and $1$ in the subset may not act as a $0$ and $1$ for the whole ring.

Comment: There could be other automorphisms of $\Bbb Z_s^k$ other than the standard one as well.

Comment: I think you have to formulate the question more correctly.